# how to check if values inside array is present codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

hi how can i check the values of an array if it is present? for example i have this table

```
------------------
id | Key | group |
------------------
1  | abc |   1   |
------------------
2  | def |   1   |
------------------
3  | abc |   2   |
------------------
```

so as you can see value 2 doesnt have the def key. if i query

```
SELECT * FROM THISTABLE WHERE GROUP = 2.
```

it will give array(id = > 1 key => abc group = 2)

how will i check the value of the array for instance

```
if(this array have the key abc){

execute this code}

if(this array have the key def){

execute this code}
```

Comment: I think in_array() is what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the problem in using `if( $this->db->get_where("THISTABLE",array('GROUP'=>2,'key'=>'def'))->num_rows() >0 ){echo 'Group have default key';}else{echo 'Group  do not have default key';}` ??

Comment: i will be fetching data in the database for example i will select group 1 and i will check if it has the key abc or key def..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in_array()` for your required result like:

**Basic Example:**

```
<?
$testArr = array('id' => 1, 
                  'key' => 'abc',
                  'group' => 2);

if(in_array('abc', $testArr)){
  echo "success";  
}
else{
  echo "failed";  
}
?>
```

Comment: does it work for example i have returned a query result in my model then i will be doing $testArr = $this->model->modelfunction()

Comment: @kev_m: offcourse, it will work. before executing check `print_r($testArr)` u will get the idea of array structure

Comment: @kev_m: pplease share in your question.